# How to handle duplicated name dependencies in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

in my `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react-transition-group": "github:foo/react-transition-group",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.4.0",
}
```

the problem is I need to keep both of them, so is there any way to do that?

Comment: The question is asked incorrectly. If you need for some reason both of them, consider explaining why. The possible solution depends on that.

Answer (score 4):

Try the **[dedupe](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe)** command in CLI,

All you have to do is to execute the below command from your project's source directory where you have your `package.json` file,

```
npm dedupe
```

After executing this command you'll see the duplicate entries are getting removed in your package.json.

Answer (score 0):

use this :
npx sort-package-json